# Why does htop show different CPU levels for processes than top or Activity Monitor?

Tags: activity-monitor, cpu, macos

I installed `htop` through `brew`, real pleasure of a view compared with `top`.

The totals across both CPUs for `top` align with the sum of totals per-CPU in `htop`. E.g. right now I see about 40% per CPU in `htop`, or 80% of `CPU, and`top` gives the right number.

But the individual processes are completely different. `CrashPlan` in `top` currently gives ~20%, and if I sum up all of the individual tasks in `top` it gets to the right total.

In `htop`, all of the individual tasks show 0.0%, even if the total per CPU is high.

In sum:

1. CPU of individual processes in `top` do not equal those in `htop`
2. The sum of CPU of individual processes in `htop` do not equal the total CPU used in `htop`.

What am I misunderstanding? How do I read `htop` results?

Comment: Does this answer help explain the differences? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65835/htop-reporting-much-higher-memory-usage-than-free-or-top

Comment: It would... if I were on Linux with `/proc`, but it doesn't exist on OS X. Maybe it is just an issue with the 0.8.x port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a permissioning problem. Answer from Linux is here https://superuser.com/questions/338749/htop-isnt-returning-cpu-or-memory-usage

Comment: If this solved your question - please consider checking this as accepted. If it didn't solve it, perhaps editing this into the question will bump it and deleting this answer will let it surface as an "unanswered question with one upvote - those tend to get answers over time"